# OAuth 1.0 signature generator for Java

Tags: library, java, authentication

I am amazed how hard it is to find a good Java OAuth 1.0 signature generator.  I am kind of looking for a large company one if possible: like Apache, Google, etc.  Google had one, but it was deprecated.

How do people normally do this?  The process looks like a pain in the butt.

Comment: OAuth 1.0 is quite old, most systems now require oAuth 2 but the old libraries for oAuth 1 should still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found signpost. https://github.com/mttkay/signpost

It also has Oauth 1.0a

Good Luck

EDIT:

Sample Usage --

```
HttpURLConnection conn = ...

OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

consumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha256MessageSigner());

// sign the request
consumer.sign(conn);
```

Comment: Can you detail the main features and some detail about the suggested software?

Comment: Only one I found, also light weight.  Bad new it requires HttpURLConnection.  That might be hard to get with some Spring connection stuff.